# How to draw maps with OpenLayers without subtitles?

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers, data, tiles, open-source-gis

I'm developing an application, using OpenLayers and OpenStreetMap, which can not have some subtitles, because it pollutes the map, subtitles like this:[image: Forest area]

[image: Preservation area]

this is my code

```
defaultRasterLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});
  var  map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [defaultRasterLayer],
        target: 'map ',
        view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2
    })
    });
```

How do I remove it?

Comment: Isn't it a requirement to show the copyright

Comment: Please define "subtitle"

Comment: @JGH these little pictures on the map, like these trees or the blue traces

Comment: For info we seem to be talking about http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=14/-1.5182/-48.4301 and http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=15/-0.6232/-47.8046 here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To apply a different symbology, you would need to either

- find a source with a style that you like
- find a source that provides vector tiles, which you can style as you wish
- download OSM data, style it and serve it on your own server

Comment: you know some server with editable vector for free?

Comment: @PedroHenrique "free" often depends on your use. You can start by [OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles), which links to openmaptiles.org but there are others.

Comment: A few other links - the source of the style that you're currently using is https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/ , https://switch2osm.org/manually-building-a-tile-server-16-04-2-lts/ covers "setting up a raster tile server" and https://ircama.github.io/osm-carto-tutorials/ has lots of useful map styling help.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately as far as I'm aware you can't, because the labels are rendered into the tiles that you're displaying.

You could use source of tiles without labels, here is an example [mc.bbbike.org](https://mc.bbbike.org/mc/?lon=13.368594&lat=52.459748&zoom=10&num=2&mt0=osm-no-labels&mt1=mapnik&marker=)